# In a webtest, how can I break out of a For loop?

Tags: performance-testing, web-testing

In a declarative Microsoft webtest, is there any way to break out of a 'For' loop?

I am using the For loop's PageCounter in my requests and am searching for something in each page response. When I find 'something', I would like to break out of the loop. I'm sure this can easily be done in code, but I would like to stick to just the declarative test script.

This is in reference to a declarative .webtest file in a Visual Studio "Web Performance and Load Test" project.

Comment: If it is a C# `for` loop then just use `if( ... ) break;`. Otherwise please explain more and show some code.

Comment: It is a declarative Microsoft webtest 'for loop', not c# coded test.

Comment: OK,, so as I said before *"please explain more and show some code"*. Code is a very general term, so show or describe what you have and what you want. The term "declarative Microsoft webtest" seems to apply to VS 2005 or 2008.

Comment: @AdrianHHH This is  using Visual Studio 2015. The 'code' involved is:
    Loop (Initialize to 1, Increment by 1, While {{Pagecounter}} < 21)
        If (The context parameter "SelectedItemBank" does not exist)
            {{AdminServer}}/item-banks/list.ssp
(If you are not familiar with Microsoft Web Performance and Load Tests, see this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out how to format (or paste image) in comment.

Comment: I am fine with web tests which is why I am willing to try and help you. However, your question is so sparse on details that I do not know what you are asking. Please [edit] the question to add the extra details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you describe the code to be:

> Loop (Initialize to 1, Increment by 1, While {{Pagecounter}} < 21) If (The context parameter "SelectedItemBank" does not exist) {{AdminServer}}/item-banks/list.ssp

You might terminate the loop early by writing a suitable value to `Pagecounter`. It is easy to write a plugin that would set the value based on some test. I am not aware of any built in facilities that will modify the control of the loop.

For one load test I wrote a few simple plugins to do simple arithmetic on context parameter values. These I used to manipulate values to control a loop. For another load test I wrote a web test loop based on a context parameter existence. A plugin set the context parameter when the loop should be terminated.

Comment: Perfect! You solved my problem. I couldn't find a way to change PageCounter, until discovered the Request Plug-in "Set Context Parameter Value". Thank you very much for getting me on the right track.